# How to retrieve the data that inserted in the map firebase fire store

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app in the android studio IDE and I want to display the inserted data in a text box
but the problem is I don't know how to retrieve the data that I inserted in the driver field. The driver field is a map, Is there a way to retrieve the data insert in the driver field? This is my firebase fire store look like, I want to get the tricycle number data.
can anyone give me example on how to retrieve a data in a map collection field?
[image: This is the picture of my fire store]

Answer (score 3):

Following the documentation on [getting data from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document), you can get a `DataSnapshot` object of the data at that location. Then using [`DocumentSnapshot#get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#public-t-get-string-field,-classt-valuetype,-documentsnapshot.servertimestampbehavior-servertimestampbehavior) to get the value of an individual field.

This can be done using:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

DocumentReference driverDocRef = db.collection("Driver Locations")
    .document(driverId);

driverDocRef.get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Driver #" + driverId + "'s Tricycle Number is " + document.get("driver.tricyclenumber", String.class));
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

To make this into a function that you can reuse elsewhere, you can make use of [`Task#onSuccessTask()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#onSuccessTask(com.google.android.gms.tasks.SuccessContinuation%3CTResult,%20TContinuationResult%3E)) to chain tasks together.

One such implementation of this would be:

```
public Task<String> getDriverTricycleNumber(String driverId) {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    DocumentReference driverDocRef = db.collection("Driver Locations")
        .document(driverId);

    return driverDocRef.get()
        .onSuccessTask(new SuccessContinuation<DocumentSnapshot, String>() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public Task<String> then(DocumentSnapshot document) {
                if (!document.exists()) {
                    throw new DriverNotFoundException(); // <-- a custom exception of your choosing
                }
                return document.get("driver.tricyclenumber", String.class);
            }
        });
}

// to use:
getDriverTricycleNumber("someDriverId")
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Number> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String tricycleNumber = task.getResult();
                Log.d(TAG, "Driver #" + driverId + "'s Tricycle Number is " + tricycleNumber);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't get tricycle number", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

**Note:** Optionally, you can simplify the above code using modern arrow notation and chaining:

```
public Task<String> getDriverTricycleNumber(String driverId) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("Driver Locations")
        .document(driverId)
        .get()
        .onSuccessTask(document -> {
            if (!document.exists()) {
                throw new DriverNotFoundException(); // <-- a custom exception of your choosing
            }
            return document.get("driver.tricyclenumber", String.class);
        });
}

getDriverTricycleNumber("someDriverId")
    .addOnSuccessListener(tricycleNumber -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "Driver #" + driverId + "'s Tricycle Number is " + tricycleNumber);
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't get tricycle number", exception);
    });
```

Comment: yo @samthecodingman thanks for the examples. really appreciate it.

Comment: @samthecodingman The `tricyclenumber` field is a String, so I changed it in your code accordingly.

Comment: @AlexMamo You missed a few spots but they have now also been corrected. However, I was under the impression that OP had used the wrong type, but even so, that Firebase would coerce them to numbers.

Comment: Yes indeed, the `Task<String>` too. I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a map, then just use completely-standard dot notation:

```
const myFirstname = data.driver.firstname;
const myLastname = data.driver.lastname
etc etc etc
```